# Basic Java concept

Tags: java

Hi I have following code block

```
public class Driver {

 static String x = "x";
 static String y = "y";

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
         setX(x);
         System.out.println("but x is still "+x);           
}

 static void setX(String x){
      x="a";
      System.out.println("now x should be = "+x);         
  }
}
```

and this prints

```
now x should be = a
but x is still x
```

I was hoping to get

```
now x should be = a
but x is still a
```

I know there are ways to get what I want,but please answer why this does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
static void setX(String x){
      //x="a"; //refers to local variable , from parameter
      //make it as follows
      Driver.x="a";
      System.out.println("now x should be = "+x);         
}
```

Comment: thanks,I just forgot the dominance of local variable over class variable.

Answer (score 3):

Well, look at your method:

```
static void setX(String x){
    x="a";
    System.out.println("now x should be = "+x);         
}
```

You can ignore the fact that you've got a static variable called `x`, because that's *hidden* by the parameter here. So it might as well not exist. As far as this method is concerned. If that's what was puzzling you, then the fix is to remove the parameter entirely:

```
// In main
setX();
...
static void setX(){
    x="a";
    System.out.println("now x should be = "+x);         
}
```

If you expected changing the value of the parameter to affect the argument as well...
All arguments are passed *by value* in Java - which means the argument is evaluated at the call-site, and that's used as the initial value for the parameter. But beyond that, the argument and the parameter aren't related - if you change the value of the parameter, that *doesn't* change the argument.

People sometimes *claim* that Java passes arguments by reference, because if the parameter type is a *mutable* reference type, then you can see change to the *object* that the parameter value refers to, and those changes will be seen by the caller:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("x");
appendHello(builder);
System.out.println(builder); // Prints xhello

...
static void appendHello(StringBuilder parameter) {
    parameter.append("hello");
}
```

That does *not* change the value of the parameter, which is just a reference - you can tell it doesn't change the value of the parameter, because there's no assignment operator...

Answer (score 1):

In `setX`, you're temporarily changing the value of the variable used to hold the actual parameter. Make the method public and change the assignment to `this.x=...` to refer to the field instead, or use `Driver.x` as @cloudeus suggested.

Comment: driver.x will do as suggested

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `Driver.x` to set the value. You cannot update the static variable with just defining `x="a"`

```
static void setX(String x){
    Driver.x="a";
    System.out.println("now x should be = "+Driver.x);    
}
```

Comment: @kandarp, Oops, that was a blunder. I fixed it

Answer (score 1):

the variable x is passed in by value (a copy) so the method doesn't change the value of the variable.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid static varibales. 
Instead use

```
public class Driver {

  private String x = "x";
  private String y = "y";

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Driver d = new Driver();
    System.out.println("Original x "+d.x);     
    d.setX("a");
    System.out.println("New x "+d.x);           
  }
  public void setX(String x){
    this.x=x;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

because you defined x as static variable. If you want to print a then remove static from x variable and replace below code in main method:

> setX(new Driver().x);
>
> System.out.println("but x is still "+new Driver().x);

Answer (score 0):

for setX() method, you'd better change the parameter from x to a or something else, e.g.:

```
setX(String a) {
    Driver.x = a;
}
```

The local variable x might have taken precedence of the static x.

Answer (score 0):

You are using static variables, and need to use the class name in accessing the variables...

```
public class Driver {

 static String x = "x";
 static String y = "y";

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
         setX(x);
         System.out.println("but x is still "+ Driver.x);           
}

 static void setX(String x){
      Driver.x="a";
      System.out.println("now x should be = "+ Driver.x);         
  }
}
```